# Auto-layout issue with UIButton with long title that compresses an aligned Segmented control which should have fixed width and should never compress

Tags: interface-builder, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout

In my Xcode 6.2 Swift project I have an issue with Auto-layout (I'm also using size classes) that I'm not able to figure out...

In Main.storyboard I have a view containing, among the others interface elements, a `UIButton` and a `UISegmentedControl` that are positioned at the same height on the opposite side of the view.

I'm setting manually all the constraints in Interface Builder (none in code) and my every view is working just fine, except in this case (and this particular issue only occurs when I have a long text).

The button is aligned to the left border of the view and its constraints are:

- Leading space to superview == 0
- Trailing space to segmented controller >= 8
- Top and bottom space to other interface elements == 8

The segmented controller (which has 2 segments) is aligned to the right border of the view and its constraints are:

- Trailing space to superview == 0
- Leading space to button >= 8
- Top and bottom space to other interface elements == 8

The button in the storyboard has a title "Some title", but actually the actual title is always set in code in `ViewWillAppear`:

```
myButton.setTitle(aStringThatSometimesIsPrettyLong, forState: .Normal)
```

**The visual result I need to achieve (on every possibile device and orientation) is that the Button title I set in code, while it can be displayed in good length in the interface, should never compromise the size of the segmented control, compressing the labels of the two segments.**
So, I want the size of the segmented control to be fixed and I'm willing to accept the fact that the Button title, if long, can be truncated with dots.
Instead, no matter what I try (and I'll explain what I've tried in a moment) **when the Button title is very long it is not truncated, instead the segmented control is compressed and therefore its two segments labels are truncated.**

So far, I've tried, separately and together, these steps:

- Adding a width minimum constraint to the segmented control.
- Incremented (in steps, up to 1000) the Content compression resistance of the segmented control while decreasing the correspondent value of the button.
- Increased (up to 1000) the Content hugging priority of the button.
- I think I can't set a maximum width to the Button, because it can stretch depending on the title set in code and, more important, on what device the app is run on.

**My biggest issue is that, no matter what I try, when I run the app I always get the same behavior (button title completely shown, un-truncated, and compressed segmented control).** It seems like adding these constraints doesn't change anything, and it never happened to me before with Auto-layout... messing up, a lot, but no change adding constraints, this is new!

Maybe the issue is that the button title is set in `ViewWillAppear` and not in the Storyboard, but my app wouldn't work properly if I couldn't set its title in code.

Last, but pretty important, I have to admit that, while I've managed so far to get Auto-layout and Size classes working on all devices and orientations for all the (over 10) viewcontrollers of my app, I've actually never written a single line of code for Auto.layout and Size classes: **I've done everything in Interface Builder and, if possible, I'd really love to continue this way**.

Any suggestion would be really, really appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Cesare

Comment: It sounds like you've tried the correct things. Namely, it should work to reduce the horizontal compression resistance priority of the button to below that of the segmented control. Things to try: log the segmented control's `intrinsicContentSize`; maybe it's failing to derive an intrinsic size from its content. Log the segmented control's `constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal`.

Comment: @KenThomases Thank you very much, the issue was indeed the segmented control intrinsicContentSize, everything's fine now. I really appreciate your help, thanks again! I'm only sorry I can't accept your answer, since it is a comment... Happy Easter!

Comment: You're welcome. Out of curiosity, how was the segmented control configured such that it didn't have an intrinsic size?

Comment: @KenThomases I'll look very bad answering this... I wasn't able to figure it out, so I deleted the segmented control and created a new one. My partial excuse is that I'm pretty new at programming, but I feel bad anyway...

Comment: Don't feel bad. I was just curious. I'm glad you got things working, even if we didn't figure out exactly what was wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

As @KenThomases pointed out, the constraints I was setting were actually right (actually, it also works with less constraints now that, thanks to his answer, I figured out the issue), but the Segmented control wasn't getting its intrinsicContentSize. Fixed that, now everything's fine.